# Lead Time and Cycle Time - Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to validate the data between the widgets Lead Time and Cycle Time with the report that imported from azure devops (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops), but when I do the average the data doesn't match. Is there some place where can I find information about how the calcule is done or which filters to perform?? Isn't that a simple average?

[Lead Time Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2mHy.png)

Comment: Could you provide more details about the issue such as what data you are struggling to put in and what is the exact error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the lead time and cycle time will also **include weekends**. So this could affect the average of the data.

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cumulative-flow-cycle-lead-time-guidance?view=azure-devops):

> Lead time is calculated from work item creation to entering a completed state. Cycle time >is calculated from first entering an In Progress state to entering a Completed state.

In PowerBI, you could check the `Completeddate` , `Cycletimedays column`,`CompletedDate`.

[image]

For example:

In chart:

[image]

Chart settings:

[image]

In Date:

[image]

The average Cycle time days:(147.183+133.340+133.340)/5 = 82.77

Here is a doc about [creating Power Bi lead time/ cycle time chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-leadcycletime?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi).

Comment: Hi Kevin, I added one exemple in the question (Lead Time Exemple). I only have one 'work item' in the Lead Time = 4.8, but the Average is 17, it make no sense to me.

Comment: Hi @Anna Luiza De Lisbôa. From the screenshot, you are using the Dashboard widget. Check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cumulative-flow-cycle-lead-time-guidance?view=azure-devops#plan-using-estimate-delivery-times-based-on-leadcycle-times),   The `Days on average` is the value used to estimate when your team will complete that work item instead of the simple average value about the points. You need to combine this value with the standard deviation to evaluate. The band around the trend line shows the standard deviation.

Comment: If you need to get the correct average value, you may refer to the doc in the answer to create the lead time chart in **Power BI**.

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT let me see if I understood. The Days On Average is not a simple average, correct? In the doc that you mentioned is not very clear about it, is only saying that the average is use to estimate when you team will complete that work.

Comment: Hi @AnnaLuizaDeLisbôa. Yes. You are right. There is indeed no detailed explanation in the document. And I could also reproduce this situation in my side. This value is only used to estimate the time for the team to complete. It is not calculated based on the points in the table. Test with Power BI, I could get the correct average time.